# CakePHP performance tuning for mobile web apps

Tags: performance, cakephp, mobile

I'm building out a transactional web app intended for mobile devices. It'll basically just allow players in a league to submit their match scores to our league admin. I've already  built it out somewhat with angularjs/JSON Services/ionic but it's very slow going. Changing requirements and very little time to work on it have me considering starting over in CakePHP (despite being fairly new to it and MVC in general).

**What coding practices can I follow to keep the user experience fast?** My cakephp source folder is massive compared to my angular source folder but if I understand correctly, that won't necessarily affect the user because most of the heavy lifting will be done by the server and presented as a fairly small website to the client, correct?

Should I try to do a big data load right when they login so that most of the data is already client side? Are there ways I can make the requests to/from the server smaller? Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of your data model, it's hard to give specific ways to optimize.

I would take a look at sending data asynchronously (client-side) with [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (or something home-grown) or using pagination to break up large sets of results into smaller subsets.

You can use something like a Real User Metric (RUM) monitor at [Pingometer](http://pingometer.com) to track performance for users. It'll show what, if anything, takes time to load - network stuff (connectivity, encryption, etc.), application code (controllers), DOM (JavaScript manipulation), or Page Rendering (images, CSS, etc.).